Rendering with OptiX in Blender 4.1
I've installed Blender 4.1 on a new computer running a GeForce RTX 4080 Super GPU and AMD Ryzen 9 7900X CPU and wonder if I should be setting the Cycles Render Devices over in Blender Preferences>System to OptiX instead of CUDA?  I'm building some rather large landscapes and volumes and can use all the help I can get.

Optix generally tends to perform slightly better than CUDA on graphics cards that support it, so since you have that option go for it

And since nobody here might have your exact hardware and the same scenes you might be building, the simplest solution is just to make your own test renders... I mean it's not a decision like what kind of GPU to buy which you could regret afterwards. It's just  the flick of a switch and you can check the render times for a scene yourself to make up your mind. Because the thing is this, if for whatever reason your hardware is faster with CUDA although OptiX usually performs better, what good is this tip from people like us then anyway?

I went with OptiX and it's looking good.  Thanks.
